# Como importar dados (.csv) para o R mantendo o formato original

Tags: r, csv

Estou tentando importar dados do Excel (já em formato .csv) para o R; os valores contidos nos arquivos a serem importados estão nos seguintes formatos, por exemplo, 8509,80...

Para fazer a importação, estou utilizado o comando:

```
variavel=read.table("dados.csv", header=T, dec=",")
```

Entretanto, quando da visualização dos dados importados, vejo que o R importou apenas a parte que não é inteira do número (no caso, o R traria para o valor de 8509,80 apenas o 80).

Desta forma, peço a gentileza de me ajudarem a fazer a importação da forma correta, ou seja, o valor de 8509,80 (em padrão inglês seria 8509.80).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir o separador dos campos. No seu caso, como deve ser o csv europeu/brasileiro, o separador provavelmente é ";".

```
variavel=read.table("dados.csv", header=T, dec=",", sep=";")
```

Um atalho para isso é usar a função `read.csv2`:

```
variavel=read.csv2("dados.csv", header=T)
```

Comment: amigo, deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

As funções do base para leitura de tabelas são suficientes para atender a maioria dos casos. No entanto, elas são relativamente lentas, e existem alternativas mais rápidas caso sejam muitos arquivos e/ou eles sejam muito grandes, que também possuem outras pequenas vantagens.

O pacote `readr` foi criado exatamente com o objetivo de melhorar as funções padrão, [nos seguintes pontos](https://github.com/hadley/readr):

- Os argumentos possuem nomes mais consistentes um com os outros (e.g. `col_names` e `col_types` e não `header` and `colClasses`).
- Sâo aproximadamente 10x mais rápidas.
- Mostram uma *progress bar* caso a leitura demore mais que alguns segundos.
- Strings não são transformadas em fatores por padrão.
- Os nomes das colunas não são transformados em expressões "válidas" do R, ou seja, as colunas mantém o nome idêntico ao original (mesmo que comecem com número, possuam espaço, etc).

Neste pacote as funções possuem nome similar às do `base`, substituindo o ponto por um underscore (_). Por exemplo:

```
#base:
variavel <- read.table("dados.csv", header=T, dec=",", sep=";")
variavel <- read.csv2("dados.csv", header=T)

#readr
library(readr)
variavel <- read_csv2("dados.csv")
```

De forma análoga, existem as funções `read_csv()`, `read_table()`, `read_delim()`, `read_tsv()`, `read_lines()` e `read_fwf()`.

Outra alternativa, também, é a função `fread()` do pacote `data.table`. A `fread()` é ainda mais rápida (cerca de 2x) que as funções do pacote `readr`, e tenta identificar automaticamente o separador, se há nome de colunas, etc. A função `fread()` possui argumentos com nomes iguais aos das funções do `base`, como `sep`, `header` e `stringsAsFactors`. Neste exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
library(data.table)
variavel <- fread("dados.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
```

Dependendo do formato dos dados, `sep` e `header` podem ser omitidos, mas na dúvida, é mais seguro colocá-los de forma explícita.

Para finalizar, é importante frisar que só faz sentido usar essas funções se a performance da leitura for um problema, ou se o pacote já for carregado de qualquer forma (no caso do `data.table`). Caso contrário, não há necessidade de carregar um pacote para fazer algo que pode ser feito de forma idêntica no `base`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: +1 só vale a pena colocar a ressalva que o `fread` geralmente dá problema de encoding se os dados tiverem muitos caracteres acentuados etc.